# How to use Z type car machine guns

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I bought Z-TYPE in the game, well I know it's worth $10,000,000 and it can be used for military work as it is full of guns

The problem is that I don't know how to enable the machine guns and how to fire

Answer (score 5):

I think you have the Z type (a purchasable car) confused with the JB 700 which appears with in built machine guns. The Z type has never had weaponry and the JB 700 unfortunately has them disabled when you purchase it from Legendary Motorsport:

> Grease up the drive shaft because this hot number has curves in all the right places. A classic luxury grand tourer, the JB 700 has been the car of choice for drunken misogynistic British spies since 1965. Dust off the tuxedo, quip a sexual double-entendre, pour yourself a martini for the road, and stumble out as everyone in the room mutters what a turd you are. **For safety reasons this vehicle's concealed weapons have been decommissioned**.

If you're looking for weaponised vehicles, your options are:

- [Rhino tank](http://gta.wikia.com/Rhino)
- [Buzzard attack helicopter](http://gta.wikia.com/Buzzard)

Both of which are available from "**www.warstock-cache-and-carry.com**" in game.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the Z-Type doesn't have attached guns; It is the JB 700 that has attached guns. However, its guns are not usable outside of the missions, [Deep Inside](http://gta.wikia.com/Deep_Inside) and [Pack Man](http://gta.wikia.com/Pack_Man).

Those playing on the PC can install the [Working JB700](https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/working-jb700) mod to allow using the JB 700's attached guns outside of its related missions. (It will be able to drop spikes / caltrops and the ejector seats will work too.)

Answer (score 0):

The Z-Type has no weapons, whereas the JB 700 does, but they are disabled due to safety reasons. There is a mission where you get to steal the car and use the guns, so if you really want to use it in action, just play the mission.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the weapons in the Z-Type.